# DropDown List LookUp from another dropdown not shows up

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 DropDownList, first is Project and second is Users. The Project don't have Column  Users directly but have Group Column, and in User There is Group Column either.  So my Query is like this,

```
public ActionResult Create(string value){

      //This is to shows ProjectList In Dropdown
      var list = db.Projects.ToList().Select(x => x.Name);
      IEnumerable<string> ProjectName;
      ProjectName = list;
      ViewBag.ProjectName = ProjectName;


      // This is to show UsersList in Dropdown
      var group = db.Projects.Where(x => x.Name == value).Select(y => y.GroupDev).FirstOrDefault();
      string NameGroup = group;
      var listuser = db.UsersModels.ToList().Where(x => x.GroupName == NameGroup).Select(y => y.Email);
      IEnumerable<string> TaskUser;
      TaskUser = listuser;
      ViewBag.Users = TaskUser;


      return View();
}
```

So my workflow will be like this , first I choose the The ProjectName from Dropdown then I will get the value from my DrowpDon using JQuery , and then I select what is the groupname based on the ProjectName. And then I create IEnumerable to shows all users that matches the GroupName. Now I dont know why its not working, it is because my logic wrong? Or My Jquery is wrong?
and here is my Jquery to do that,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Project').change(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var value = $('#Project option:selected').text();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/TaskModels/Create',
            data: {
                value: value
            },
            type: 'POST',


        });
    });
});
```

and here is my Dropdown,

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Project, new SelectList(ViewBag.ProjectName, "Project"), "Pilih Project ")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User, new SelectList(ViewBag.Users, "User"), "Pilih User")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
      </div>
```

and I already add my script too in my scripts Section,

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   <script src="~/Custom_Script/DropDownListenere.js"></script>
}
```

Anyone can help mere here ? I'm assuming this is because my jquery, its because I don't familiar with that language.

Comment: You ajax call does not do anything with the the view that your `Create()` method returns. But in any case, you code is not not correct. Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) from how to implement cascading dropdownlists

Comment: so i dont return the selected option in my ajax ?

Comment: add the following to your view - `<div id="test"></div>` and then add the following to the ajax - `success: function(response) { $('#test').html(response); }` - and then you will understand :) Study the DotNetFiddle

Comment: its still not working, what i need is the ajax to return the value that i selected and just that. Maybe i need to create partial view ? because once i create checkbox for IsDone and when checkbox is checked the text decortain will be line-through , and before im using the partial view i need to refersh the page before the text is changed dynamicly.

Comment: Study the code in the fiddle!!!

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks its already work but i have question tough. In my ajax im passing int Id to  my controller, and call it in my Action from parameter ,do the query and   return it as Json and thats work. but now the question why when im passing string GroupName to my controller from jquery it didnt work , i already change the selectlist to ("GroupName", "Name") . my first assumption is i cant pass string to my controller and need int?, im already change the data that i pass to my  controller to  GroupName: $(this).text() and $('#Project option:selected').text() but its not working

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot guess your code. You need to ask a new question and show the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one more action (Example : GetUser()) which accepts a parameter(selected Project) and returns User list as JSON. Then change the change event of the Project Drop down as :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#Project').change(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var value = $('#Project option:selected').text();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/TaskModels/GetUser', //Call GetUser Action instead of Create.
        data: {
            value: value
        },
        type: 'POST',  
        success:function(data){    //add this success function
            $("#User").html(""); //To clear the existing options.
            data.forEach(function (user) { //Iterate through the output array (In this case list of user emails)

                $("#User").append($("<option></option>") //append options to User drop downs
                    .attr("value",user)
                    .text(user))
            })
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Do i need use JsonResult in my action ? because when i use something else it still not working

Comment: hmm hi do you have idea how to debug it i set breakpoint in GetUsers Method, but its never stop there i want to see weather is the value null or not

Comment: Debugging will work as usual. If not, there might be some issue with your ajax call. Could you please open chrome developer tool and check network if you are using chrome?

Comment: im using firefox , bu there is developer tool as well . And how i can use it to debug ? im still very new in this sorry. or maybe is this because im not passing a int id and passing string?but  my GroupName is unique key .

Comment: Open the network tab in developer tool and click on any option in the drop down. Then your action call will be listed there. Please check what's the status of the call

Answer (score 0):

U can use Append users result from the server response with id GroupName Example : $('#Project').change(function () { var self = $(this); var value = $('#Project option:selected').text(); $.ajax({ url: '/TaskModels/Create', data: { value: value }, type: 'POST', success: function (data) { $.each(items, function (i, item) { $('#mySelect').append($('', { value: item.id, text: item.username })); }); } }); });

Comment: That would be a bit pointless since OP is returning a view, not json!

Comment: This post is not properly formatted and needs proper punctuation and full sentences.  After correcting the English, please put each code line onto a separate line and then highlight all code and click the format button that looks like { }